# Setting values in a DataFrame based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have big datasets of more than 1 million rows and varying column size(sometimes 1 column or sometimes different number of columns). initially, I created a script, it was working fine. but recently I ran into an issue which can be replicated with the below script.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0],'b':[100,1]})
df[df>0]='S1'
df[df==0]='S0'
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value
```

line 3 and 4 can be interchangeable and the issue will be at the 4th line.

initial df:

```
a b
0 100
0 1
```

Expecting df:

```
a  b
S0 S1
S0 S1
```

Comment: What is the issue? Can you add results or a stack trace with the undesirable behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DataFrame-wide replacements, that isn't quite right. Use `where` or `mask`:

```
df = df.where(df == 0, 'S1').where(df > 0, 'S0')
df
    a   b
0  S0  S1
1  S0  S1
```

Alternatively, you can use `np.select`:

```
df[:] = np.select([df > 0, df == 0], ['S1', 'S0'], default=df)
df
    a   b
0  S0  S1
1  S0  S1
```

Comment: Hi, Your solution works but why my approach is wrong? any idea?

Comment: @BhanuTez `df[df>0]` produces a DataFrame masked by NaNs having the same shape and size as the original DataFrame, so there is no way for pandas to know exactly what you are trying to assign.

Comment: @BhanuTez No, your method does not work with DataFrames (Series, yes!), and will not work for the foreseeable future.